# render changes as soon as there is change in backend

Tags: angular

i want to render changes on frontend as soon as there is change in backend without refreshing the page.
there is a functionality in my app to update userDetails in my app but in different component and i am getting initials in different component. i have getUserData() on oninit so initially it renders initials but when i make changes, i have to refreash page to see changes. how to render changes without refreshing

```
  getUserData(): void {
    this.usersService.getUser().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        let firstName = response.user.name.first;
        let lastName = response.user.name.last;
        this.color = response.user.profileBackgroundColor;
        this.initials = `${firstName} ${lastName}`
          .split(" ")
          .map((n) => n[0])
          .join("")
          .toUpperCase();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  getUserData(): void {
    this.usersService.getUser().subscribe(
      (response) => {
        let firstName = response.user.name.first;
        let lastName = response.user.name.last;
        this.usersService.color = response.user.profileBackgroundColor;
        this.usersService.initials = `${firstName} ${lastName}`
          .split(" ")
          .map((n) => n[0])
          .join("")
          .toUpperCase();
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

update value in service this.usersService.initials, this.usersService.color . use this to display value and inject this service in other component. fetch data from userService directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventEmitter, using emit() you can Emit an event containing a given value.
if you need to communicate between child and parent component, it can be done as below

```
@Component({
    selector : 'child',
    template : `
        <button (click)="sendNotification()">Notify my parent!</button>
    `
})
class Child {
    @Output() notifyParent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    sendNotification() {
        this.notifyParent.emit('Some value to send to the parent');
    }
}

@Component({
    selector : 'parent',
    template : `
        <child (notifyParent)="getNotification($event)"></child>
    `
})
class Parent {
    getNotification(evt) {
        // Do something with the notification (evt) sent by the child!
    }
}
```